# jQuery Accordion tab should close when the sidebar is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have sidebar which opens when the plus icon is clicked and it has a an accordion, which can be opened and when the sidebar is closed without closing accordion. The accordion stays open.

Is there a way if the sidebar is closed the accordion should auto close.

Please see the below code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/kefq1bxo/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn"></i>
</div>

<div class="cd-panel from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container">
        Content
        <div class="nav-accord2">
                    <div id="accordion">
          <h3 >Header</h3>
          <div>Text 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn-a
    if($('.cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

$( function() {
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-caret-1-s",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-caret-1-n"
    };
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      icons: icons
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
      } else {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
      }
    });
  } );
  $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion('option', {active: false});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/kefq1bxo/1/)